# PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "B" when expecting one of the following

Tags: oracle, plsql

```
BEGIN
  DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_JOB(
    JOB_NAME          => 'BillsDueCheck',
    JOB_TYPE          => 'PLSQL_BLOCK',
    JOB_ACTION        => 'BEGIN
                            UPDATE Customer C
                            SET C.Standing = 'B'
                            WHERE C.CustomerID IN (
                              SELECT B.CUSTOMERID
                              FROM Bill B
                              WHERE (BillDate + 60) < SYSDATE);
                          END;',
    START_DATE        => SYSTIMESTAMP,
    REPEAT_INTERVAL   => 'FREQ=DAILY'
    END_DATE          => NULL,
    ENABLED           => TRUE,
    COMMENTS          => 'Checks if the bill is overdue'
  );
END;
```

The error occurs at the SET line I think I must be doing something wrong further up but I'm not sure.

I have tried running the job action by it's self and it works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must double your quotes around your 'B' otherwise oracle will think your string is terminated and try to interpret the B as a command.

```
BEGIN
  DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_JOB(
    JOB_NAME          => 'BillsDueCheck',
    JOB_TYPE          => 'PLSQL_BLOCK',
    JOB_ACTION        => 'BEGIN
                            UPDATE Customer C
                            SET C.Standing = ''B''
                            WHERE C.CustomerID IN (
                              SELECT B.CUSTOMERID
                              FROM Bill B
                              WHERE (BillDate + 60) < SYSDATE);
                          END;',
    START_DATE        => SYSTIMESTAMP,
    REPEAT_INTERVAL   => 'FREQ=DAILY'
    END_DATE          => NULL,
    ENABLED           => TRUE,
    COMMENTS          => 'Checks if the bill is overdue'
  );
END;
```

Comment: Sometimes if you have a lot of quotes in a string it can become hard to read with a lot of double quotes. Then an alternative is using the "q" notation, like for example `q'[This isn't using double quotes]'`.

Comment: you wouldn't also happen to know how to check if the schedule is running would you? would it be somewhere here? http://puu.sh/ceuSU/94668cdb4a.png